# Zend Navigation Breadcrumb and Menu links issue for Album Module

Tags: zend-framework, menu, navigation, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

I have noticed a bug. While gone though following reference link, I have created Album module and set Navigation Breadcrumb and Menu as per documented.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/tutorial.navigation.html

I noticed:
1. if current active page = home, then works expected.
2. if current active page = album, then also works fine.
2.1 if  current active page = album and after clicked **Add new album** link, then there is issue in href link in Navigation menu and breadcrumb for Album module (ie, http://zendfassignments.local/album/add instead of http://zendfassignments.local/album )

Similar issue is for edit and delete album also. So its not possible to get back on album module page.

How can I fixed this issue?

Comment: is there a question in here? :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by Replacing with the following code in **modules/Application/config/module.config.php** file.

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Album',
            'route' => 'album',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'params' => array('id' => null),
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Add',
                    'route' => 'album',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Edit',
                    'route' => 'album',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Delete',
                    'route' => 'album',
                    'action' => 'delete',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

And enjoy the Zend Framework... :)